# Can you sell shares before ex-dividend and buy back after, to replace 'dividend income' by 'capital gains'?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss

Note: this is the opposite direction than most sell/buy questions over dividend day.

Here is the situation: I have large losses from unrelated trading activity, and can only deduct 3000 per year from income.

I am considering to sell large amounts of short-term bond ETF investments (for example VUSB) right before the ex-dividend day, and buy them back right afterwards, repeating this every month-end (they pay dividends/interest every month). This results in a monthly capital gain that should be roughly equivalent to the avoided dividends, but *it is combinable with the pending losses*! - which the dividends/interest is not.

This way, I should be able to reduce my taxable income by more than the normal 3000 limit (using up some 'losses' instead of moving them in future years).

Is there any problem with this, or would this work?

Comment: If the dividends are classified as dividends and not interest you'd be losing the qualified dividends treatment for them. So you'd be saving less in taxes, but sooner.

Comment: Monthly dividends / interest from bonds ETFs is never considered 'qualified'... at least from my experience of many years.

Comment: Then it should probably work absent some extreme unexpected market movement during that time

Comment: Odds of it making enough difference to be worth the effort seem low.

Comment: at the current interest rates, one can potentially recover several more thousands of dollars of restricted carry over capital losses, so may be worth the effort if one stashes a large amount in bonds *anyway*.